# How would you set up a unsupervised model to prevent it from creating clusters around known groups?

Tags: clustering

I think my question could be best represented by an example.

I choose n number of people and I get them to each write 1000s of descriptions of pieces of art that are unknown to me (no label given). The set of pieces of art that a person describes is not consistent between the each person and a person could write multiple descriptions about the same piece of art.

If I know who wrote each description but not what they wrote about and assuming that each person has a very distinctive writing style, how would I set up an unsupervised model if I explicitly don't want it to create clusters based on the person writing the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look up techniques that people use for fairness and/or (differential) privacy. There, people use various techniques that try to e.g. change internal representations of neural networks so that they no longer - even indirectly - contain certain information. One such approach is to use an adverserial model (compare the generative adverserial approach as a classic example of adverserial training), which in your case would aim to classify the author of the text (multi-class classification). At the same time your "main model" would try to build good embeddings/representations as judged by some other metric, while being penalized for constructing them in such as way that allows the adversery to classify the author.